# What is $\mathcal O( Y _0 \cup Y_1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$
$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}$

So I am looking at Hartshorne 3.4(a), where he proves that for $Y \subset \mathbb P^n$, $O(Y)=$constants.  I want to prove this result by induction on $n$.

He already showed that $\mathcal O(Y)$ is an invariant of the isomorphism type of the variety, and that $\O(Y_i)=\A(Y_i)$.  And he shows before he begins the proof of 3.4(a) that $\A(Y_i)$ is the $0$th graded component of the graded localization $S(Y)_{(x_i)}$
.

> Question:  Let $n \geq 3$.  What is $\O(Y_0 \cup Y_1)$ expressed as a localization of $S(Y)$?

I'm pretty sure it should be given as the $0$th graded component of the localization of $S(Y)=\A(cone(Y))$ to the open set in the cone $D_{x_0} \cup D_{x_1}$.

And I am 65% sure that this can be expressed more simply as the $0$th graded component "localization of $S(Y)$ at the two functions $x_0$ and $x_1$."  Here I need to figure out what the quotes mean.

Comment: This is annoying by induction, and the terminology that Hartshorne has define at this point isn't quite sufficient for a good proof. You know that P^n has the affine cover (Prop. 2.2). For n=1, if you have a regular function defined everywhere, what must the conditions be for it to agree on both open sets? Try to do the same for n=2 and the 3 open sets.

Comment: $\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
These are the compatibility axioms of the sheaf $\mathcal O(Y)$.  We have the mayer vietoris sequence $0 \to \mathcal O(Y_1 \cup Y_2) \to \mathcal O(Y_1) \oplus \mathcal O(Y_2) \to \mathcal O(Y_1 \cap Y_2)$.  This implies that the $\mathcal O(Y_1 \cap Y_2)$ is the intersection $\mathcal O(Y_1) \cap \mathcal O(Y_2)$ where the intersection is taken inside $K(Y)$(since all of these sections can be viewed as living in $K(Y)$.   .The condition for $f$ to be regular in $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is that the function be in the intersection $A(Y_1) \cap A(Y_2)$ taken inside $K(Y)$.